# How to create a method that takes array list as argument?

Tags: java, array, methods, list

To create a method that takes an array as an argument, you would do this:

```
public static void printAges(int[] age) { // prints ages to screen
    for (int x = 0; x < age.length; x++) {
        System.out.println("Age: " + age[x]);
    }
}
```

How would you create a method like this one with one exception, that it takes an array list as an argument instead of an array?

Thanks. -- Krishna

Comment: This belongs on StackOverflow. Hint: `int[]` is the name of a type, and `ArrayList<int>` is the name of a different type.

Comment: I'll move the question to Stack Overflow. @Caleth

Answer (score 2):

1. Best practices would have you generalize the argument such that instead of working with the concrete class `ArrayList` you would work with an abstracted interface, here, `List`.  This way you would be able to reuse this implementation for every class that supports `List`, not just `ArrayList`.
2. You are looping over the array using a `byte` loop control variable.  This is rather unusual (i.e. error prone).  FYI, there is no performance gain for `byte`-typed variable over a more expected `int` type.  The `byte` type will begin to fail with numbers larger than 7 bits (e.g. 128).  Suggest you use the `int` type for integral loop control and indexing variables.
3. There are good alternatives to using looping based on incrementing an integer.  `foreach` is one construct, and lambdas are another.  These constructs will work better across the broad set of classes that implement the `List` interface.  The `foreach` construct uses an iterator, which is easy to use and under the covers is specialized by the specific collection being used.  The lambda approach uses a `map`-style operation where you supply a function to be invoked on each element, leaving the iteration totally out of your code.  Lambda's support composition, so you can filter before mapping, for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;

 public class ListReturn6 {

public static List getSubList(List<Integer> list) {
    List<Integer> subList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (Integer a : list) {
        if (a > 50) {
            subList.add(a);
        }
    }
    return subList;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    intList.add(24);
    intList.add(45);
    intList.add(99);
    intList.add(44);
    intList.add(77);
    intList.add(40);
    intList.add(87);
    List<Integer> subList = getSubList(intList);
    System.out.println("Sub list is");
    for (Integer a : subList) {
        System.out.print(a + " ");
    }

  }
}
```

In Main method created a List named intList.

Added elements there and passed to method ListReturn6'method getSubList()

getSubList  signature is

```
 public static List getSubList(List<Integer> list)
```

By looking parameter you can see that this method is taking List of integers as argument

After procession this method is also returning list.

You can checkout https://ebhor.com/java-return-arrays/